# Yii2: Filtering a GridView boolean column with SwitchInput

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I was wondering if there is a way to make the tristate version of [SwitchInput](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/switchinput#basic-usage) widget as a filter for a bool column in a GridView?
It’s rendering correctly but it’s not updating on change (Select2 does though).

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'enabled',
            'format'    => 'boolean',
            'filter'    => SwitchInput::widget([
                'name' => 'DeviceSearch[enabled]',
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'value' => $searchModel->enabled,
                'tristate' => true
            ])
        ]
```

Last column:
[image: GridView]

Comment: how are you filtering the records show your searchmodel

Comment: If understand correct, you can add in `options` an `onchange()` event where you can define to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [GridView from Kartik](https://demos.krajee.com/grid) it lets extend the base colum to add filterType, so:

```
[
            'attribute' => 'enabled',
            'format'    => 'boolean',
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SWITCH,
]
```

Will generate an SwitchInput widget as a filter on top, you need to configurate the rest of parameters, or at least the required ones for the switch input filter type.